# Encrypt .deb content

Tags: debian, encryption, dpkg, deb

I have a .deb package that I want to install in my customers devices. Currently I have these packages in a private repository that can only be accessed with a private key. But I also want to prevent the customers (or anyone that is able to download the package) to unpack it and see/change the code. My idea was to have a deb package that can only be installed/unpacked if a decryption key was present in the system, but this seems to no be very easily done.

My thought was to have two .deb packages. One 'normal' package that I already have (let's call it inner package) and another package (the outer package) that the only thing that it has is:

- The encrypted inner package, that will place in /tmp/inner.deb.enc
- In the postinst script, checks if there is the decrypt key and, if it does, decrypts the inner package and installs it.

This has a critical problem. In the postinst script I install the inner deb like this: `dpkg -i /tmp/inner.deb`. So when I try to install the outer package I get the following error `dpkg: error: dpkg database lock was locked by another process with pid 10024`. I believe that this is due to when the outer package is being installed, it locks the dpkg database, and trying to invoke dpkg again within that process (to install the inner package) will conflict with the outer installation's lock.

If change `dpkg -i /tmp/inner.deb` to `apt install /tmp/inner.deb` I have a similar problem where when I try to install the outer package it waits for the lock to be released.

Is there any suggestion on what to do? Either following this line of thinking or with something totally different.

Comment: Once it is unpacked and decrypted, there's nothing to stop them from then examining the installed files to their heart's content

Comment: Yes but the idea is that you can only unpack/install it if you have the decryption key. If you have the key I'm ok if you know the contents and the installed files. If you do not have it you cannot know the "anything" of the package.

Comment: Then just encrypt the package like you would encrypt any other file? Why go to all this trouble of double package installation and what not?

Comment: @muru
Like that I cannot do something like `sudo apt install my-package`. This would force me to manually get the encrypted file, decrypt it and then install it.

Comment: If that's the case, then you can put an encrypted archive in the package and just extract it (not install using dpkg) in the postinst script. But at the point you might as well just make a password-protected zip file, you're not really gaining anything from the packaging system.

Comment: Yeah I though of this and I got to the same conclusion. Like that I could not remove the install package (and maybe the upgrades could not work). I really wanted to use the packaging system and all its advantages

Comment: This is one case where you can't really have your cake and eat it too. Really, encrypting the package itself is probably best. Sure, you need to do an extra step for the first time installation, but after that you can set up a timer or cronjob to download updated packages and prompt the user to decrypt so that the upgrade can be done.